# apple's appstore : while updating my app from appstore, it installs as separate application.What is the reason for that?

Tags: app-store

i've developed an application and posted in apple's appstore. Now i've modified some features  in it. Posted the updates in appstore. The appstore approved my updates. Now when i try to update my app in iphone, an Install button is there in itunes and the app installed as a separate application. What is the reason for that? Plz give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you (accidentally?) change the bundle identifier of your app?